# WCF Service not communicating on same server

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

WCF is deployed on IIS7 and access over the network AND Website(ASP.NET C#) is also deployed on same server. Over the network WCF communicate successfully but On localhost server WCF does not communicate with website.
my configuration for wcf is

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWITSService" closeTimeout="00:00:05"
                  openTimeout="00:00:05" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:00:05"
                  bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                  maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
                  textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <!--<reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />-->
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" />


                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:4570/WITSWCFService.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWITSService"
              contract="WITS.IWITSService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IWITSService" >
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

AND Website Configuration is given below

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding  name="BasicHttpBinding_IWITSService" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"  />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <!--<webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
      </webHttpBinding>-->
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WITSService.WITSService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WITSService.WITSService"   />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>


  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: **What is the error !** Does it works if you put the IP Adress instead of the localhost alias? Is there any corporate proxy setup on the computer, that could compromise the communication?

Comment: no, it only works when website is not deployed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are running on `localhost` only or `localhost:4570`.  If you are using port `4570` you'll need to open it up on a real server.

What does the WCF endpoint return if you hit the URL in the browser, that is usually very telling of the problem.